# Привязать кнопку-картинку к фону

Tags: html, css

[image: хелп]

```
     .button{
                background-image:url('b1.jpg'); 
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 2;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -220px; 
                margin-top: 150px;


            }
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <title>Online store</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="descritpion" content="Online store on sale of electronics">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


 <div class="image">
        <img src="2.jpg" alt="Online Store" class="logo ">
        <div class="button">
                <a href="place.html"><img  src="b1.jpg" alt"Place"></a>
            </div>
        <h2>Tourism</h2>

</head>
<body>
        <h1>Турзим - это важная составляющая нашей жизни</h1>

</body>
```

Как привязать картинку посередине фона, она стояла уже везде, но только не там, где нужно. У меня скоро истерика начнется(

Comment: Кстати на заметку - все видимое содержимое сайта надо в body писать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в стили **.button** следующее:

```
.button {
    background-image:url('b1.jpg'); 
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px; // тут укажите половину ширины кнопки
    margin-top: -20px; // тут укажите половину высоты кнопки
    width: 200px; // укажите ширину картинки для кнопки
    height: 40px; // укажите высоту картинки для кнопки
}
```

Comment: Выровнялось идеально. Но возникла проблема в том, что при появлении скрола по вертикали, при добавлении новой информации на сайт, картинка едет строго вниз

Comment: Попробуйте значение top сменить с % на px и + у вас блок image не закрыт

Comment: Как написали выше, закройте блок img, а также дайте ему стиль `position: relative`, который будет родительским для внутренней кнопки.

Comment: Всё получилось! Спасибо большое)))

Comment: не забывайте ставить галочку!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.button {
  background-image: url('b1.jpg'); 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: #07f; /*цвет вместо картинки*/
  /* Вот это нужно добавить */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px; /*Ширина как у img*/
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto; /*по высоте 0 отступ, а по ширине автоматический*/
}

.button img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px; /* Желательно выставить статичную ширину */
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <a href="place.html"><img src="b1.jpg" alt="Place"></a>
</div>
```